# I am getting this sbt error , Is there any way to fix this issue

Tags: sbt

I have this issue while running sbt package command

```
C:\Users\U101\IdeaProjects\sbt1>sbt package
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Oracle Corporation Java 10.0.2)
[info] loading global plugins from C:\Users\U101\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] loading project definition from C:\Users\U101\IdeaProjects\sbt1\project
[info] loading settings for project sbt1 from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to sbt1 (in build file:/C:/Users/U1081739/IdeaProjects/sbt1/)
[info] compiling 10 Scala sources to C:\Users\U1081739\IdeaProjects\sbt1\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.11' for Scala 2.11.12. Compiling...
 error: java.lang.NullPointerException
  | => sat scala.reflect.io.JavaToolsPlatformArchive.iterator(ZipArchive.scala:301)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.foreach(AbstractFile.scala:92)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.traverse(ClassPath.scala:277)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15(ClassPath.scala:299)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:299)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:264)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:358)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
```

Can you help please

JDK installed is 1.8 in my laptop

[image]

I added jdk 8 in my environment variables, i also installed sbt sbt-0.13.18 , i dont know how it takes sbt 1.4.7

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java 8 given _"welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Oracle Corporation Java 10.0.2)"_? Can you check the latest sbt 1.4.8 with Java 8 or (better) Java 11?

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10871?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski    I added jdk 8 in my environment variables, i also installed sbt sbt-0.13.18 , i dont know how it takes sbt 1.4.7